# Meteor app: Error invoking Method 'saveProject': Internal server error [500]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, compiler-errors

I am new to using Meteor and when trying to add a new project the console throws this error; Error invoking Method 'saveProject': Internal server error [500]. Is there a way to fix this??

Here is my saveProject method;

```
'saveProject':function(project){
    check(project.name,String);
    project.userId = Meteor.userId();
    project.dateentered = new Date();
    project.lastupdate = new Date();
    if(!project.datedue){
      project.datedue = new Date();
    }
    if(!project.customer){
      project.customer = Customers.findOne({})._id;
    }
    project.invited = [];
    return Projects.insert(project);
  }
```

Here is the template that calls it;

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'keyup input[type=text]': function(event,tmpl) {
    if(event.which === 27 || event.which === 13){
      event.preventDefault();
      var project = {};
      project.name = tmpl.find('#projectNameEnter').value;
      Meteor.call('saveProject',project);
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: What does the server say?

Comment: Meteor.publish('projects',function(userId){
          return Projects.find({$or:[{invited:this.userId},{userId:this.userId}]});
    });

Comment: i am using the differential boilerplate as a starting point; https://github.com/Differential/meteor-boilerplate

Comment: I meant, what does the server shows in your terminal window?

Comment: Exception while invoking method 'saveProject' TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Comment: You are using the `_id` key for `undefined`. findOne() returns an object but in your case I think "Customers" is just an empty collection.

Comment: Thank you adding the customer worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the method, I was trying to find a customer id in an empty collection. By adding a customer first I was able to add a project